# WebStorm UTF-8 encoding not showing emojis

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

What encoding should I use in WebStorm to see/display the emojis in the source code?

Right now using `utf-8` is not showing the emojis.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is not currently supported :(

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-111788 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

---

**UPDATE (2017-02-09)**: This is a work in progress so hopefully it will be **fully available in 2017.1 final**.

[2017.1 EAP builds](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/WebStorm+EAP) already have such support (from first EAP build).

Here is a screenshot IntelliJ IDEA (it uses the same code base for editor features):

[image]

From: https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2016/12/intellij-idea-2017-1-eap-is-open/

> Emoji
>
> The code editor now correctly handles Unicode emoji characters. On Mac OS X emoji characters are rendered as colored images. On Windows and Linux emoji are rendered as monochrome characters. Go ahead and use emoji in comments, String literals and resources.

---

Here is screenshot from the Rider IDE (same editor code base in this regard):

[image]

Comment: The new Version 2017.1 is out but i just don't know how to use this emojis. What do i have to enter or press to insert an emoji?

Comment: @Spen TBH -- no idea -- not using them myself. But have a look here: http://getemoji.com/ (link taken from this Tweet: https://twitter.com/jetbrains/status/828574134133256194)

Comment: Yes, thx! Copy pasting them does work. I was expecting autocomplete or any menu to appear. Also they are only in gray and white on Windows :/

Comment: @Spen you must install a plugin to do that: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9174-emoji-support-plugin

Comment: too late, I already moved to `atom` I was a hardcore webstorm user, but I had to let webstorm go :/ ...

Comment: Emojis aren't displayed on Linux, but there's a [workaround](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-192107#focus=streamItem-27-4144606.0-0).